# ESP-32-WROOM-32EU PCB design

Tags: circuit-design, pcb-design, sensor, esp32, review

[image: 3D][image: Bottom-Layer][image: Top-Layer][image: ESP32-WROOM-32EU]

I have started a PCB design and I have tried to add an [SHT45](https://sensirion.com/media/documents/33FD6951/6555C40E/Sensirion_Datasheet_SHT4x.pdf) sensor to my ESP32 chip board for my IoT project.

Could you check my design for any issues? I am also open to recommendations.

Is the battery connection safe?
Update: I realized that connecting the battery to the same regulator as the USB connection would harm U3, so I made the connection to another regulator.
[image]
Could you check final design? I would be happy if you help me to improve myself.

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p7Dv.png):

Comment: How it should work so we can say if it works like you expect or not? Also you talk about PCB design but that is only the schematic. What part of the schematic needs commenting? How it is drawn, the connections there, component values, or what? Some things are drawn upside down for some reason. At least provide a link to each and every component you want someone to check. And open-ended review questions are not very popular here because there is no clear question that has a clear answer. Your only question is if there is any issues, and the short answer is "yes".

Comment: With a quick glance I happened to notice that U2 may be missing a net label on the Vin net/pin.

Comment: Upside down and sideways GND symbols will void any warranty, implied or otherwise.

Comment: I am sorry for lack of info I have to make sure my schematic after that I will start to pcb design. Here, I am sharing with you my resources. chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Espressif-Systems-ESP32-WROOM-32UE-N4_C701344.pdf

Comment: https://sensirion.com/media/documents/33FD6951/63E1087C/Datasheet_SHT4x_1.pdf

Comment: Why do you want to shortcut the 3.3 V supply with KEY1 and SW1?

Comment: As far as I know, these types of pull-up resistors are used to ensure noise stability. This is going to be my first project in PCB design. I am working on filling the gaps in my knowledge and researching potential errors in my design to improve and develop my skills. Thank you for your understanding.